# How to fix topbar dropdown menu links not working in Foundation 6

Tags: javascript, html, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I have never used Foundation 6 before and after building an entire website on it, I realized the links in my topbar's drop down menu do not work. I searched for an answer to this question everywhere and I have seen so many different answers. Some say to download a newer version of foundation.min.js, some say to download a newer version of foundation.topbar.js, and others think this issue cannot be solved.

Below is some of code (my website can be found at http://littleeternities.com so that you can see for yourself what I mean by the links not "working").

TopBar Code

```
    <!--Navigation-->
    <div class="title-bar" data-responsive-toggle="main-menu" data-hide-     for="medium">
    <button class="menu-icon" type="button" data-toggle></button>
  <div class="title-bar-title">Menu</div>
</div>
<div class="top-bar" id="main-menu">
  <div class="top-bar-left">
    <ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="top-bar-right">
    <ul class="menu vertical medium-horizontal" data-responsive-menu="drilldown medium-dropdown">
      <li class="has-submenu">
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <ul class="submenu menu vertical" data-submenu>
          <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="has-submenu">
        <a href="#">Services</a>
        <ul class="submenu menu vertical" data-submenu>
          <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Custom Blog Design</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Custom Web Design</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Pre-Made Templates</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Branding Packages</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Web-Hosting</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="has-submenu">
        <a href="#">Courses</a>
        <ul class="submenu menu vertical" data-submenu>
          <li><a href="#">Perfect Your Business Plan</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Kickstart Your Badass Online Business</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Digital Innovator</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">More Courses</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="has-submenu">
        <a href="#">Free</a>
        <ul class="submenu menu vertical" data-submenu>
          <li><a href="#">Kickstart Your Badass Business Checklist</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">FREE Course: Build a Better Business in 7 Days</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Business Brainstorming Workbook</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/">8 Business Tools to Use</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /navigation -->
```

Here are the scripts added

```
<script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/what-input/what-input.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/foundation-sites/dist/foundation.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/app.js"></script>
   <script src="../bower_components/foundation-sites/dist/foundation.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/foundation.topbar.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/foundation-sites/js/foundation.offcanvas.js"></script>
```

In the file app.js, the following JavaScript is written

```
$(document).foundation();

$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

I have tried every method thus far to fix this, now I'm just stuck. Any answers will be uber appreciated! :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be? `$(document).ready(function() {
$(document).foundation();
});` So that foundation service is called on `DOM` ready.

Comment: @ParkashKumar Thanks! I updated the app.js file with your code and its still not working. Do you advise something else?

Comment: There is another issue in you `app.js`. This one: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function` Either add owl-carousel plugin or comment this code, if you are not using.

Comment: Also, you have `foundation.js` and `foundation.min.js`. Aren't they same? If both are sources of same plugin (normal & minified), remove one.

Comment: @ParkashKumar I see, I removed the OwlCarousel plugin and deleted the minified version of the foundation plugin. Issue still exists.

Comment: Try removing plugins one by one, and identify first, which plugin is causing issue with the navigation.

Comment: There seems to be issue with the sequence of the plugins used. Re-arrange it as, `1. jquery.js, 2. foundation.topbar.js, 3.what-input.js, 4.foundation.min.js, 5.foundation.offcanvas.js` and finally `app.js`.

Comment: Also, it would be suitable, if you create fiddle for further investigation.

Comment: @ParkashKumar I did exactly what you said - remove plugins one at a time and I found that the problem lied in the foundation.js file. It turns out the plugin version was incorrect so I went over to https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/blob/develop/dist/foundation.js and downloaded the correct one and it worked! Thanks so much for your help! Go ahead and write it as an answer so I could up vote it! :)

Comment: Sure, I am wrapping my comment in an answer, so that it might be useful for other in future.

Comment: One thing more, add `foundation.topbar.js` after `foundation.min.js`, as it is dependent on it.

Comment: @ParkashKumar Got it! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be couple of issues:

1. In you `app.js`, move `$(document).foundation();` inside `$(document).ready(function(){});`.
2. Resolve `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function` being initiated from `app.js`, Either add owl-carousel plugin or comment this code, if you are not using.
3. Either use `foundation.js` (normal) or `foundation.min.js` (minified), but don't use both if they are same.
4. Try removing plugins one at a time, and identify first, which plugin is causing issue with the navigation.
5. There seems to be issue with the sequence of the plugins used. Re-arrange it as, 
   i. `jquery.js`,
   ii. `what-input.js`,
   iii. `foundation.min.js`,
   iv. `foundation.topbar.js`,
   v. `foundation.offcanvas.js`
   vi. `app.js`
6. As per your comment, problem lied in `foundation.js` and getting the latest one from [foundation.js](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/blob/develop/dist/foundation.js) resolved it.

Comment: @Zobia Alvi, I have posted my comments as answer, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you so much! I was so lost with Foundation. :)